# Ganymed-ssh - how to set timeout to close session when execCommand takes more time

Tags: java, session, ssh

I'm using Ganymed-ssh to pull log details remotely. Below is my code. Sometimes the data returned by stdout is huge and so it takes more time to return. I want to close the session if the stdout did not return in 1 minute. How to set timeout for session to close automatically is stdout took more than 1 minute ?

```
Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
conn.connect();
boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);
if (isAuthenticated == false)
   throw new IOException("Authentication failed.");
Session session = conn.openSession();
session.execCommand("grep traceid trace.log");
InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(session.getStdout());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
while (true)
     {
         String line = br.readLine();
         if (line == null)
              break;
         System.out.println(line);
      }
System.out.println("ExitCode: " + session.getExitStatus());
session.close();
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [waitForCondition](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Session.html#waitForCondition%28int,%20long%29) method
or [waitUntilDataAvailable](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Session.html#waitUntilDataAvailable%28long%29) method of Session Class.
Both needs timeout parameter.